# Removing Duplicate Rows in Fusion Tables

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Just using the Fusion Tables through Google Drive, and every time I merge some tables, some of the data gets duplicated, so I am just wondering, how can I remove duplicate rows from my table?

I have been unable to find anything on that for fusion tables, and I can't do it outside and then re-import because then I will exceed my Geocoding limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't update or delete rows from **View** or **Merged** tables. Depending on what you're trying to achieve you may be able to use Fusion Tables' SQL commands to create a View table that generates the results you need without duplicates. But that involves using the Fusion Tables API (V2) via a programming language( like *Java*, *Python* or Google's own *Apps Script*); you'd basically be setting up custom filter conditions using code (you can't do this from the Fusion Tables GUI).

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of setting up a SQL Command to create a view table?

Comment: I would need to know what your data looks like to write a proper SQL command to filter out duplicates. I can walk you thru it but the comment section isn't a good place to discuss it as its a fairly involved process. (Plus there are a number of things to setup/configure before even writing a line of code).  StackOverflow has a new [chat service](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) we could use. Send me an invite and we can go from there.

Comment: Ok, thanks! When I get a chance I will send you a chat invite, might not be for a few days though.